# Invoking a same method just once in java

Tags: java, string, search

I have four different classes classA, classB, classC and classD. All the four classes have the same static method search() which takes two string parameters. If i want to invoke static method search in four different classes from main class at once. How can I do that. For now my code is as follows for main class. I need to execute the same thing for other 3 classes also. How can i do that and display the results of other 3 in the same way as for classA. The way search is done in 4 classes r different but they should give the same result.

```
Main() {

    Object[] zy;

    for (String pattern : Read.arrayList) {
        List<Integer> results = ClassA.findAll(pattern, dataToSearch);
        zy = results.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < zy.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Pattern searched " + pattern + " match is found at index : "+ results);
        }
    }
    if (zy.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Nothing matched");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason the methods must be static? This seems like a good candidate for an interface method.

Comment: Agreed.  The [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you change this to non-static methods. Look how easy and nice is when you will seperate an interface:

```
public interface Common {
    List<Integer> findAll(String pattern, String dataToSearch);
}

public class A implements Common ...
public class B implements Common ...
public class C implements Common ...
public class D implements Common ...

// in main:
List<Common> allYourClasses = new ArrayList<Common>();
allYourClasses.add(new A());
allYourClasses.add(new B());
allYourClasses.add(new C());
allYourClasses.add(new D());

List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Common c : allYourClasses) {
    result.addAll(c.findAll(pattern, dataToSearch));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - You should NOT do this. Avoid static methods. One of the reason being they can not be called without the exact class. A group of classes that implement a simple interfaces will work faster, safer and better in every way

2 - You can (but you shouldn't) do something like this:

```
    for (Class<?> clazz : new Class[] { ClassA.class, ClassB.class,
            ClassC.class }) {

        Object[] zy = null;
        String dataToSearch = "";
        String[] arrayList = { "a" };
        for (String pattern : arrayList) {

            List<Integer> results = findAllForClass(clazz, pattern,
                    dataToSearch);
            zy = results.toArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < zy.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(" Pattern searched " + pattern
                        + " match is found at index : " + results);
            }
        }
        if (zy.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Nothing matched");
        }
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Integer> findAllForClass(Class<?> clazz, String pattern,
        String dataToSearch) {
    List<Integer> list = null;
    try {
        list = (List<Integer>) clazz.getDeclaredMethod("findAll", String.class,
                String.class).invoke(null, pattern, dataToSearch);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        list = Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return list;
}
```

You see the @supresswarning and the try/catch? well, this is a hint: is telling you you this code is at least suspicious. It is in fact unsafe, non well performant, and is a stupid workaround.

(But we all did something like that once in our lives)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really figure out why would anyone do that.

That said, you could have a method taking a Class as a parameter and calling the method explicitly by name (getMethod.../invoke()).

That puts you back in non static world and you can iterate over the classes you want to invoke. (But again, why use statics in the first place?)

Pseudo untested code:

```
public void invokeStatic(Class clazz, String method, Class<?> paramsTypes[], Object[] params) {
    Method method = clazz.getMethod(method, paramsType);
    method.invoke(params);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to group all of the results together, just keep adding results to your list:

```
List<Integer> results = ClassA.findAll(pattern, dataToSearch);
results.addAll(ClassB.findAll(pattern, dataToSearch));
// etc.
```

Comment: If the first match of pattern is found, it gives the result of Class A and Class B together. Then if other match of pattern is found it again gives the result of Class A and Class B together. Is there a way by which I can print all the results of class A together, followed by class B and so on?

Comment: @Xyz Xyz, look at my answer: It will call findAll for A B C and D and all matches will put into final result list. So after for-loop you will have in result all Integers founded by A, B, C or D